# Android: How to set Orientation for View

Tags: android, orientation

I have one service, on started one View appears on top of all views.

If I rotate my mobile to landscape, then the view orientation changes to landscape but I want to make the view portrait only. How can I do this?

Comment: Add `android:screenOrientation="portrait"` in the manifest file under the activity in which you have your view.
`

Comment: that is not a activity.. my view is open when volume down button press..

Comment: But your view must be inside something? Show us your code.

Comment: there is one service

public class ViewService extends Service{


}
at startcommand i'm inflate the view and add into the Window.

that service is sticky and started when app is launch first time..

Comment: I guess you are misusing the word "Service". Service is invisible, Activities are visible. There are no views in a Service!

Comment: The view you are inflating, that would be an activity. So add the above line for that.

Comment: No.. you are not getting my point... ok thanks for help..

Comment: If that's the case, show the code of your service class and your manifest file. It might solve the misunderstandings (if any!).

Answer (score 3):

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT); }
```

or

```
setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
```

Comment: Add it to your activity, it will work @Sangha_development

Comment: please share more info @Sangha_development

Answer (score 3):

To declare that your activity handles a configuration change, edit the appropriate `<activity>` element in your manifest file to include the `android:configChanges` attribute with a value that represents the configuration you want to handle.

For example, the following manifest code declares an activity that handles both the screen orientation change and keyboard availability change:

```
<activity android:name=".MyActivity"
          android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
          android:label="@string/app_name">
```

Now, when one of these configurations change, MyActivity does not restart. Instead, the MyActivity receives a call to onConfigurationChanged(). This method is passed a Configuration object that specifies the new device configuration. By reading fields in the Configuration, you can determine the new configuration and make appropriate changes by updating the resources used in your interface.

For example, the following onConfigurationChanged() implementation checks the current device orientation:

```
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);

    // Checks the orientation of the screen
    if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "landscape", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } else if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT){
        Toast.makeText(this, "portrait", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

**Or Simply**

The screenOrientation is the attribute of activity element. The orientation of android activity can be portrait, landscape, sensor, unspecified etc. You need to define it in the AndroidManifest.xml file. For example:

```
<activity  
            android:name="com.example.screenorientation.MainActivity"  
            android:label="@string/app_name"   
            android:screenOrientation="landscape"  
            >
```

But as per my experience you need to set **For targeting Android 3.2** and above, you need BOTH

```
android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
```

Reference : http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html

**EDIT :**

**Android screen orientation Lifecycle**

We might have some confusion on the android screen orientation change lifecycle of an Android activity.  Sometimes you might observe  that your activity getting restarted, while the you rotate the device. Sometimes nothing happens. Below is the simple rule for android screen orientation change lifecycle.

**1**. If you already `@Override` the `onConfigurationChanged()` function in your java code( in your Android activity class) for handle Android Screen Orientation Change. Then your activity will never restart for any screen orientation changes.

**2**. If you do not `@Override onConfigurationChanged()` function as above, then your running activity will get restart every time for any screen orientation change happens in your device. That means your activity will destroy first by calling `onDestroy()` API and then `onCreate()` method will call again for your running activity to restart it.

**3**. To properly handle your activity’s restart state, you need to restores its previous state through the normal Activity lifecycle, in which Android OS calls `onSaveInstanceState()` method before it destroys your activity. So that you can save your data(variable values)and your application state. You can then restore the previous state during `onCreate()` or `onRestoreInstanceState()` method call of your activity.

Hope it will help you.

Comment: @Sangha_development : So which view you have ?

Answer (score 1):

Please find below an example which give better idea for achieve your task.

```
public class MainScreenOrientation extends Activity {

    private static final String TAG = "MainScreenOrientation";

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        mContext = this;

        setContentView(R.layout.main_activity);

        startService(new Intent(this, MyOwnService.class) );
    }
}
```

In my MyOwnService service class

```
public class MyOwnService extends Service {
    private static final String TAG = "MyOwnService";
    private static Context mContext;
    private static final String BCAST_CONFIGCHANGED = "android.intent.action.CONFIGURATION_CHANGED";

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        mContext = this;

        IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter();
        intentFilter.addAction(BCAST_CONFIGCHANGED);
        this.registerReceiver(mBroadcastReceiver, intentFilter);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {           
        Log.d(TAG, "onDestroy()");
        //Unregister receiver to avoid memory leaks
        mContext.unregisterReceiver(mBroadcastReceiver);
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart(Intent intent, int startid) {

    }

    public BroadcastReceiver mBroadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent myIntent) {

            if (myIntent.getAction().equals( BCAST_CONFIGCHANGED)) {

                Log.d(TAG, "received->" + BCAST_CONFIGCHANGED);


                if(getResources().getConfiguration().orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE){
                    // it's Landscape
                    Log.d(TAG, "LANDSCAPE");
                }
                else {
                    Log.d(TAG, "PORTRAIT");
                }
            }
        }
    };
}
```

And at last in manifest file

```
<service android:enabled="true"  android:name="com.android.example.services.MyOwnService">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.CONFIGURATION_CHANGED"/>
            </intent-filter>
</service>
```

Hope it helps you.

Answer (score 0):

Try to set the orientation programatically when view is open.

setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);

Comment: Yes.. and for that activity i already set screen orientation in manifest as well as in Oncreate()

Answer (score 0):

In your Manifest file make sure to set the right orientation, like this:

```
<activity android:name=".SomeActivity"
android:label="@string/app_name"
android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
```

This way Portrait Mode is forced, and your App will not change to Landscape when you rotate your device.

Comment: So what do you want to do? Let the whole app change orientation but fix this single View to Portrait?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want your View to be fixed in Portrait Mode, but the rest of your app to freely rotate whenever you rotate your device.

In this case, you would need to catch orientation changes, and then rotate your View counterwise to the current rotation.

Something like this:

```
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) 
{
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    View yourView = ....;

    // Checks the orientation of the screen
    if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) 
    {
        yourView.setRotation(-90);
    } 
    else if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT)
    {
        yourView.setRotation(90);
    }
}
```

You also have to edit the appropriate element in your manifest file.

```
      <activity android:name=".MyActivity"
         android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
         android:label="@string/app_name">
```

I'm not sure on the degree values and can't check this right now, you might have to test this.

Nevertheless, this way you could keep your View always in Portrait mode.